# Using Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA Only for the Dependencies Aspect

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

- Intellij: 2018.3
- Gradle: 4.10.3
- Java: 10
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

I want to use Gradle dependencies in IntelliJ, but not any of the build/compile aspect of Gradle. After I import build.gradle, the runner starts a build which takes a long time, and fails midway, with some cryptic message like "Invalid tag type ...". So I don't see any of the Gradle dependencies setup either External Libraries or in the project settings dialog.

I realize developers can still run a Gradle compile task on their own since I use a Gradle Java plugin. I think the error encountered during the compile phase is preventing IntelliJ from settings up the dependencies.

I have a Java project with multiple modules. The project contains a structure as follows:

```
 DATA
  build.gradle
  DATA.iml
 DOMAIN
  build.gradle
  DOMAIN.iml
 SERVICE
  build.gradle
  SERVICE.iml
 WEB
  build.gradle
  WEB.iml
 build.gradle
 settings.gradle
 MyProject.ipr
```

This is an enterprise environment, so my developer machine may be locked down in some ways; it's possible.

Comment: 1) Can you build from command line by Gradle? 2) Please give the full error output. 3) See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560 about directories to exclude from AV/firewall

Comment: No, on this machine, a Gradle build typically fails with some error related not being able to resolve a dependency conflict. I think it's related to marking a repo as one that can handle snapshots (an admin settings). I'm also not able to change antivirus settings. But when I loaded the build file in Intellij, the dependencies did seems to get downloaded. It's just that the next step is a Gradle compile which fails as I described with none of the dependencies being setup in IntelliJ. I'm only using a Java plugin in my build file.